# Canvas View going out of screen

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have added an Image inside a Canvas view with this code.

```
<Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
        <Image  x:Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/test.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Canvas>
```

But the Image is going out of View.

[image: Screenshot]

What is going wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are needed to set `Height` n `Width` of image n the `Stretch` Property to `Fill` for it doesnt go out of Your Canvas

```
    <Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent"
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
        <Image  x:Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/test.png" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: I have already tried that as suggested in other answers. not helping

Comment: I have implemented it with very large 1920*1080 size image. Its working. Just put the above code into your ContentPanel Grid.

Comment: Hey Thanks. Was not setting height and width for image.

Answer (score 2):

*Canvas* was designed to work like that. Consider using other UIElements or if you insist on using *Canvas* then one of the solutins may be to set Binding in Width/Height of the Image:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent" 
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
    <Image Width="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanelCanavas, Path=ActualWidth}" 
           Height="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanelCanavas, Path=ActualHeight}"
           x:Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/test.png" Stretch="Uniform" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Canvas>
```

Of course you can bind to `Canvas` (as above) or to `LayoutRoot`. Also define how the Image should be streched (if `Uniform` or `UniformToFill`).

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/image.png" 
        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" 
        Stretch="Fill"></Image>
```

OR

```
<Grid Width="..." Height="...">
            <Image  Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/image.png" 
                    Stretch="Fill"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Image>
        </Grid>
```

Hope this helps.....

Comment: did you tried both of the above solution? which version are you using windows phone 8 or windows phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of a `Canvas`. When you change the `Canvas` into a `StackPanel` it will work:

```
<Stackpanel x:Name="ContentPanelCanavas" Background="Transparent"
            Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
        <Image x:Name="StartLogo" Source="/Assets/test.png" Stretch="Fill" />
</Stackpanel>
```

Comment: I wish to keep it canvas. Isn't there a fix for this